# How can I store an array in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I should store in the cell of a dataframe an array of strings, but the error is
*ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable*

I declared an array of words like this:
`words = []`
I have some text to extract words from and I put the words into the array.
`for word in text: words.append(word)`

And I have a dataframe column declared like this:
`dataframe['Words'] = ''`

The error is triggered by:
`dataframe.loc[x, 'Words'] = words`

I should be able to store an array in a dataframe.

For example, if
`text = 'Today is a sunny day'` 
I tokenize the sentence, and each token is a word.
I put each word in `words`
I would like the column `Words` of dataframe to be:
`'Today', 'is', 'a', 'sunny', 'day'`

Comment: try `dataframe['Words'] = words`, and also check that your `words` list looks as you expect first. You might need to `.split(' ')` your text first to get it as you want

Comment: can you clarify what is `x`? and `text`?

Comment: @Pep_8_Guardiola It doesn't work, there is still the ValueError .
Also, I tokenize the text before storing the words in the array, I don't know if that will give me any problems.

Comment: @mozway x is the line of the dataframe, text is an unstructured text. I extract some words based on a dictionary and put them into `words`

Comment: I meant, please give explicit and reproducible examples and also provide the exact matching expected output. What you want is currently ambiguous.

Comment: @mozway I tried to make an example above, I don't know if it's ok like this

Comment: Check my answer, if this is not what you want, please provide your DataFrame constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not fully clear. In any case, assigning a list to a DataFrame's cell is not easy as a DataFrame is not designed to hold iterables. Pandas checks that the right-hand side of an assignment has the correct length, which doesn't work well with iterables like lists. In addition, you should rarely have to assign to single cells.

You can use a Series to force correct indexing:

```
text = 'Today is a sunny day'
words = text.split()
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=['Words'])
x = 1
dataframe.loc[[x], 'Words'] = pd.Series([words], index=[x])
```

Output:

```
                        Words
0                         NaN
1  [Today, is, a, sunny, day]
2                         NaN
```

*Note that the key `x` must be pre-existing, if this is not the case, a workaround might be to first assign a dummy value (e.g., NaN), then to assign the list.*

```
x = 3
dataframe.loc[x, 'Words'] = np.nan
dataframe.loc[[x], 'Words'] = pd.Series([['A', 'B', 'C']], index=[x])
```

Output:

```
                        Words
0                         NaN
1  [Today, is, a, sunny, day]
2                         NaN
3                   [A, B, C]
```